# python sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, python-3.x, converters, typeerror, rdflib

I'm trying to convert a local `.xml` file to `.ttl` and I used this code:

```
import rdflib
g=rdflib.Graph()

g.parse("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\public-12T23.xml",format='xml')
print (g.serialize(format='turtle'))
```

and I got this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d52cc014f61e> in <module>()
      2 g=rdflib.Graph()
      3 
----> 4 g.parse("C:\\Users\\Saeid\\Desktop\\public-12T23.xml", format='xml')
      5 print (g.serialize(format='turtle'))

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py in parse(self, >source, publicID, format, location, file, data, **args)
   1041         parser = plugin.get(format, Parser)()
   1042         try:
-> 1043             parser.parse(source, self, **args)
   1044         finally:
   1045             if source.auto_close:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\rdfxml.py >in parse(self, source, sink, **args)
    576         # content_handler.reset()
    577         # self._parser.reset()
--> 578         self._parser.parse(source)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py in parse(self, source)
    108         self.reset()
    109         self._cont_handler.setDocumentLocator(ExpatLocator(self))
--> 110         xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
    111 
    112     def prepareParser(self, source):

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py in parse(self, source)
    123         buffer = file.read(self._bufsize)
    124         while buffer:
--> 125             self.feed(buffer)
    126             buffer = file.read(self._bufsize)
    127         self.close()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py in feed(self, data, >isFinal)
    208             # document. When feeding chunks, they are not normally >final -
    209             # except when invoked from close.
--> 210             self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
    211         except expat.error as e:
    212             exc = SAXParseException(expat.ErrorString(e.code), e, self)

..\Modules\pyexpat.c in EndElement()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py in end_element_ns(self, >name)
    368             pair = tuple(pair)
    369 
--> 370         self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
    371 
    372     # this is not used (call directly to ContentHandler)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\rdfxml.py >in endElementNS(self, name, qname)
    158 
    159     def endElementNS(self, name, qname):
--> 160         self.current.end(name, qname)
    161         self.stack.pop()
    162 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\rdfxml.py >in node_element_end(self, name, qname)
    330         if self.parent.object and self.current != self.stack[2]:
    331 
--> 332             self.error("Repeat node-elements inside property elements: >%s"%"".join(name))
    333 
    334         self.parent.object = self.current.subject

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

I know that it was not as easy as I was thought, but I got the same error when I used these script [here](https://github.com/WimPessemier/rdfconvert/blob/master/rdfconvert.py).

Comment: Please include the **full traceback** so we can diagnose where the exception is raised and how Python got there.

Comment: What is `graph` in your code? That name is never assigned to.

Comment: `"destination=output.txt"` certainly looks wrong. Did you mean to use `destination="output.txt"` perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for your quick reply. as  graph() i must say, instead of using the full name i used g=rdflib.Graph() and the as for the other comment, this problem does not rise from 
"destination=output.txt"  , because it worked in other scripts of mine just fine. the link that i also provided basically used the same script ( of course in much fancier way!!). thanks in advanced for your help.

Comment: Your input XML is malformed. Find yourself an XML validator and fix the input file.

Comment: i just changed that command to ' print (g.serialize(format='turtle')) ' instead of  ' g.serialize(destination='output.txt', format='turtle') ', but the problem remains the same :(

Comment: Look closely at the traceback. It is the `g.parse(...)` call that fails, deep inside the XML parser. That the parse error throws this traceback is probably a bug in the `rdfxml.py` module, but it was trying to tell you about an issue with your XML file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so , the problem is not related to my code, am i correct? or  should I change my code too ? because i think converting from xml to ttl should not be that easy

Comment: It's not related to your code.

Comment: You *could* [open an issue with rdflib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/issues) about that traceback. Include the minimum XML sample you can find (reduce your input file) that reproduces that traceback. It indicates an error in the rdflib error handling.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, i'm going to try xml validator to see what happens.

Comment: Having a look at the [relevant source code](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/rdflib/plugins/parsers/rdfxml.py#L327-L335) I see what happens; the `name` element is a tuple, and the first element can be `None` if there is no namespace. Your XML document contains elements without a proper namespace.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/issues/748; feel free to add a testcase.